# How can I match strings containing M digits and N letters in any order?

Tags: regex, perl

I'd like an expression that matches strings with exactly 7 digits and 5 letters in any order.

Examples:

```
123abcdf4567
f541hg342gf3
```

Comment: Hi Sergey. Your question is quite common here and doesn't show the smallest research background. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking your next question.

Comment: Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and
[this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking,
as those will help you get more and better answers from the community.

Answer (score 2):

Does it have to be a regex pattern? I'd use

```
length($_) == 12 && /^(?:\D*\d){7}/ && /^(?:\PL*\pL){5}/
```

This checks that the string contains 12 chars, of which at least 7 are digits and at least 5 are letters. This will thus only succeed if the string contains exactly 7 digits and 5 letters.

Answer (score 1):

There may be some regex extension that can do this but it is far simpler to just count the letters and digits and make sure you have the correct values.

I have a suspicion that the pattern you are requesting isn't "regular" though.

Answer (score 1):

First - I agree with the comments made - try to improve your "questionaskingskills" til next time ;)

Second - you can do this with two positive look-aheads. Like this:

```
^(?=(?:\pL*\d){7}\pL*$)(?=(?:\d*\pL){5}\d*$)
```

The first positive look ahead (a regex pattern enclosed by `(?=` and `)` - tests for a pattern of any number of non digits + **a** digit, which repeats 7 times. It may be followed by any number of non digits.

Then there's a second positive look ahead testing for a pattern of `any number of non letters` + **a** letter. This should repeat 5 times. It may be followed by any number of non letters.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/eR4lN9/4).

(To illustrate I've added an actual match at the end of the demo (`.*`). This isn't necessary.)

Comment: Note: This approach wouldn't work for checking if a string *contains* a substring matching the pattern (but the OP didn't ask for that).

Answer (score 1):

The following pattern can be used to efficiently check if a string contains a substring matching the pattern:

(?^u:(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\pL(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d))|\d(?:\pL(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\d\pL\pL\pL))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\pL(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d)))|\d(?:\pL(?:\pL(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\pL(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d))|\d(?:\pL(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\d\pL\pL\pL))|\d(?:\pL(?:\pL(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\d\pL\pL\pL)|\d\pL\pL\pL\pL)))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\pL(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d))|\d(?:\pL(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\d\pL\pL\pL))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\pL(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d)))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\pL(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d\d))))|\d(?:\pL(?:\pL(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\pL(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d))|\d(?:\pL(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\d\pL\pL\pL))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\pL(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d)))|\d(?:\pL(?:\pL(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\pL(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d))|\d(?:\pL(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\d\pL\pL\pL))|\d(?:\pL(?:\pL(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\d\pL\pL\pL)|\d\pL\pL\pL\pL)))|\d(?:\pL(?:\pL(?:\pL(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\pL(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d))|\d(?:\pL(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\d\pL\pL\pL))|\d(?:\pL(?:\pL(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\d\pL\pL\pL)|\d\pL\pL\pL\pL))|\d(?:\pL(?:\pL(?:\pL(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\d\pL\pL\pL)|\d\pL\pL\pL\pL)|\d\pL\pL\pL\pL\pL))))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\pL(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d))|\d(?:\pL(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\d\pL\pL\pL))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\pL(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d)))|\d(?:\pL(?:\pL(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\pL(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d))|\d(?:\pL(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\d\pL\pL\pL))|\d(?:\pL(?:\pL(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\d\pL\pL\pL)|\d\pL\pL\pL\pL)))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\pL(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d))|\d(?:\pL(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\d\pL\pL\pL))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\pL(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d)))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\pL(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d\d))))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\pL(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d))|\d(?:\pL(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\d\pL\pL\pL))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\pL(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d)))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\pL(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d\d)))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\pL(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d\d\d)))))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\pL(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d))|\d(?:\pL(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\d\pL\pL\pL))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\pL(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d)))|\d(?:\pL(?:\pL(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\pL(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d))|\d(?:\pL(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\d\pL\pL\pL))|\d(?:\pL(?:\pL(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\d\pL\pL\pL)|\d\pL\pL\pL\pL)))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\pL(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d))|\d(?:\pL(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\d\pL\pL\pL))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\pL(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d)))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\pL(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d\d))))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\pL(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d))|\d(?:\pL(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\d\pL\pL\pL))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\pL(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d)))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\pL(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d\d)))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\pL(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d\d\d))))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\pL(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d))|\d(?:\pL(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\d\pL\pL\pL))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\pL(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d)))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\pL(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d\d)))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\pL(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d\d\d)))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\pL(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d\d\d\d)))))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\pL(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d))|\d(?:\pL(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\d\pL\pL\pL))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\pL(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d)))|\d(?:\pL(?:\pL(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\pL(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d))|\d(?:\pL(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\d\pL\pL\pL))|\d(?:\pL(?:\pL(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\d\pL\pL\pL)|\d\pL\pL\pL\pL)))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\pL(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d))|\d(?:\pL(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\d\pL\pL\pL))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\pL(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d)))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\pL(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d\d))))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\pL(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d))|\d(?:\pL(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\d\pL\pL\pL))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\pL(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d)))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\pL(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d\d)))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\pL(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d\d\d))))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\pL(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d))|\d(?:\pL(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\d\pL\pL\pL))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\pL(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d)))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\pL(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d\d)))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\pL(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d\d\d)))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\pL(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d\d\d\d))))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\pL(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d))|\d(?:\pL(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\d\pL\pL\pL))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\pL(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d)))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\pL(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d\d)))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\pL(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d\d\d)))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\pL(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d\d\d\d)))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\pL(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\d\pL\pL)|\pL(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d\d\d\d))|\pL(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\pL|\pL\d)|\pL\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d\d\d\d)|\pL\d\d\d\d\d\d\d))))))

The above was generated using the following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use Algorithm::Loops qw( NextPermute );
use re               qw( regexp_pattern );
use Regexp::Assemble qw( );

# Regexp::Assemble doesn't support \p
my @list = sort ( ('d')x7, ('l')x5 );

my $ra = Regexp::Assemble->new();
do {
   $ra->add(join('', @list));
} while NextPermute(@list);

my $re = $ra->re()

my ($pat, $mods) = regexp_pattern($re);
my %map = ( d => '\\d', l => '\\pL' );
$pat =~ s/([dl])/$map{$1}/g;
$re = eval("qr/\$pat/$mods");

say $re;
```

Regexp::Assemble probably doesn't help in Perl 5.10+. In fact, it might even hurt. If so, you could simply use the following generator instead:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use Algorithm::Loops qw( NextPermute );

my @list = sort ( ('\\d')x7, ('\\pL')x5 );

my @alts;
do {
   push @alts, join '', @list;
} while NextPermute(@list);

my $pat = join "|", @alts;
my $re = qr/$pat/;
say $re;
```

Comment: +1 for the excellent demonstration that a regex may be the wrong tool for solving this particular problem....

Comment: @tjd, Or at least a hand written one. The generated regex should be quite efficient, especially for finding if a string *contains* a substring matching the pattern.

Comment: Beautiful. +1 for what I've learned to understand your answer. Next I'll figure out how to write my own NextPermute.